# Macbook - should bluetooth devices be turned off manually after sleep?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, bluetooth

I have Macbook Pro M1 2020 and set of bluetooth devices - MX Keys and MX Anywhere 3. I wonder if NOT switching them off causes any problems in macbook sleep or battery drain of logitech devices?

Typically, I do not switch them off but maybe it would be a good practise in order to preserve battery.

Comment: I never turn off anything and experience no problem, but on a different machine. Also Bluetooth uses so little power, I doubt it has any serious impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth's drain on your Mac is negligible, especially compared to everything else using power, and given that you're talking about a mouse and keyboard. Audio devices would use more but even then, it's not much.

Your M1 Mac is well optimized for battery. The hassle of turning your devices on and off are not worth it. Furthermore, those devices most likely have auto-off or auto-sleep to preserve their own power, which impacts how frequently they're going to poll your Mac.